# investments/transactions/get endpoint - how long to return data?

Tags: plaid

I've been testing Plaid's investments transactions endpoint (investments/transactions/get) in development.

I'm encountering issues with highly variable delays for data to be returned (following the product initialization with Link). Plaid states that it takes 1–2 minutes to return investment transaction data, but I've found that in practice, it can be up to several hours before the data is returned.

Anyone else using this endpoint and getting data returned within 1–2 minutes, or is it generally a longer wait?

If it is a longer wait, do you simply wait for the DEFAULT_UPDATE webhook before you retrieve the data?

So far, my experience with their investments/transactions/get has been problematic (missing transactions, product doesn't work as described in their docs, limited sandbox dataset, etc.) so I'm very interested in hearing from anyone with more experience with this endpoint.

Do you find this endpoint generally reliable, and the data provided to be usable, or have you had issues? I've not seen any issues with investments/holdings/get, so I'm hoping that my problems are unusual, and I just need to push through it.

I'm testing in development with my own brokerage accounts, so I know what the underlying transactions are compared to what Plaid is returning to me. My calls are set up correctly, and I can't get a helpful answer from Plaid support.

Comment: Yes, I've used the `investments/transactions/get` before and the data is very spotty.    Investment Transactions are nearly always incomplete for the first day or so.  Can even take up to a week to get accurate data.  Even after getting accurate data, the transaction data may not be the complete list.  Would expect more for a paid service

Answer (score 0):

I took at look at the support issue and it does appear like the problem you're hitting is related to a bug (or two different bugs, in this case).

However, for posterity/anyone else reading this question, I looked it up and the general answer to the question is that the endpoint in the general case is pretty fast -- P95 latency for calling `/investments/transactions/get` is currently about 1 second (initial calls on an Item will be higher latency as they have more data to fetch and because they are blocked on Plaid's extracting the data for the Item for the first time -- hence the 1-2 minute guidance in the docs).

In addition, Investments updates at some major brokerages are scheduled to happen only overnight after market close, so there might be a delay of 12+ hours between making a trade and seeing that trade be returned by the API.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to deal with a lot more than you ever imagine no matter if it's Plaid, Yodlee, or others that get data from providers.  They are limited to what the provider allow, so if you're building an app for up to date investment data you'll be navigating around landmines as you go.  For example, Ally Bank/Financial uses a third-party datalink and they do not provide "holdings" data, so if you have your user link their Ally account there will be no stock holding data. If you're wanting to hit the API and trigger updates outside of the data feed that Plaid or Yodlee and the others provide, you're going to deal with IsRealTimeMFA issues and won't be able to get the updates at will without the user inputting MFA codes all the time, which isn't going to happen.  So you will not be able to services users from Robinhood, TSP (Thrift Savings Plan) Mutual of American and many others. The product buildout landmines are by discovery and it sucks and sucks and sucks.  So many issues that are unknown.  We are continually in discovery on API/data issues.  Best of luck.